# tomar cotizacion de pagina web

Tags: vb.net

Necesito tomar el valor del dolar, de una pagina web, ya que necesito que este constantemente actualizado, para multiplicar ciertos productos por el valor del dolar.

Por ejemplo de esta pagina: https://www.bcv.org.ve/

He revisado muchos ejemplos y resultan con otras paginas web, pero con esta en especifico no funciona

he intentado recorrer todos los div pero no funciona

```
 Try
        Dim divs = NAVEGADOR.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("div") ' Obtiene todos los elementos <div> de la página web
        For Each div As HtmlElement In divs ' Recorre la lista de elementos <div>
            Dim className As String = div.GetAttribute("className")
            MsgBox(className) ' Obtiene el atributo [class] (nos servirá de filtro)
            If className = "col-sm-6 col-xs-6" Then ' El texto con el que se compara es el que muestra el valor del dólar en pesos argentinos
                TextBox1.Text = div.InnerText ' Se obtiene el valor del dólar
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

y he tratado con este otro codigo

```
Try
        Dim pre As Double
        For Each ETIQUETA As HtmlElement In NAVEGADOR.Document.All
            MsgBox(ETIQUETA.ToString)
            If ETIQUETA.TagName = "dolar" Then
                If ETIQUETA.GetAttribute("CLASSNAME").Contains("col-sm-6 col-xs-6") Then
                    pre = CType(ETIQUETA.InnerText, Double)
                    TextBox1.Text = pre.ToString("N2")
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

y nada con ninguno de los dos reconoce la etiqueta

este es parte del codigo de la pagina de donde deseo tomar la cotizacion.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 textp">—</div> 
<div id="euro" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">—</div> 
<div id="yuan" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">—</div> 
<div id="lira" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">—</div> 
<div id="rublo" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">—</div> 
<div id="dolar" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">—</div> 
<div class="pull-right dinpro center">—</div> ::after </div>
```

Comment: Pero si tienes un elemento `div` con un `id` llamado `dolar`, de allí puedes obtener directamente el contenido de los hijos, entre los cuales se encuentra el valor que buscas. ¿Porqué capturar el elemento según la clase?

Comment: es que no lo consigue o no lo toma en cuenta, el bloque for no recorre todas las etiquetas

Comment: este es parte del codigo de la pagina de donde deseo tomar la cotizacion. <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 textp">—</div> <div id="euro" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">—</div> <div id="yuan" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">—</div> <div id="lira" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">—</div> <div id="rublo" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">—</div> <div id="dolar" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">—</div> <div class="pull-right dinpro center">—</div> ::after </div>